# How to remove tooltip hints in thunderbird?

Tags: linux, thunderbird

I am using **ThunderBird 11.0.1** on Linux. How do I remove tooltip messages? I do not want tooltip hints at all. I looked at preferences and see nothing there.

Comment: Not a programming question. This is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Options** → **Advanced** → **Config Editor**. Then set `browser.chrome.toolbar_tips` to `false`.

Comment: Search for browser.chrome.toolbar_tips and click on it to toggle

Answer (score 0):

You could get the source, remove the tooltips, compile your own version. Ok, my answer is a bit flip. But at least it's possible.

Did you try this link? [Thunderbird Settings](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Modify_Thunderbird_settings)

Might be worth trying the setting from FireFox in the prefs.js...long shot but...if you want it worth a try.

Comment: thanks. But there got to be a simpler way? ON firefox, I use about:config and searched for 'tip' and saw the option there and made it false.

Answer (score 0):

The config editor is easy!  Under MacOS it is Preferences -> Config Editor...